# Java - Why windows dispatcher don't see current memory level my process?

Tags: java, windows, memory, jvm

After run my java app, I see the data of windows dispatcher and my java app has memory

figure 1: memory in windows dispatcher

[image: figure 1: memory in windows dispatcher]

it's 2GB (1988 MB).

And after that I rerun my app and see th NetBeans profiler

figure 2: memory in NetBeans profiler

[image: figure 2: memory in NetBeans profiler]

And NetBeans profiler saw that my java app have 1GB (and +- 100 to 250 MB).
And if I test it this code (use spring boot, use request to my java app)

figure 3: controller of browser request

[image: figure 3: controller of browser request]

And i can see this data of memory in browser:

figure 4: memory in browser

[image: figure 4: memory in browser]

I know that this numbers say me numbers of memory which my app used.

And I confused:

1. NetBeans profiler: 1GB (+- 100-200MB);
2. Browser: 1GB (+-)
3. Windows dispatcher: 2GB (+-)

Rerun my app a few times I always show that 3) Windows dispatcher have 2 GB (and 1) and 2) have 1GB) differences are 2 times.

My app have 1 GB and 1 GB something else. I know when I run my app, launch jre, and jre maybe take 1 GB, I read about PermGen and MetaSpace, and still could not understand what exactly takes up so much memory. I know that the task manager displays "memory" as private bytes without a swap file.

And gc don't clear this data cache.

Can you tell the task manager to deceive about the amount of process memory? How can he calculate memory differently, not the same environment with a profiler? Help me figure this out, I will be glad for any information, thanks in advance.

Comment: The heap is not the only memory area. If your application allocates any native memory at all, this could explain the difference. The OS might also be measuring the size of shared libraries and executables, but those shouldn't add up to 1GB.

Comment: [Memory footprint of a Java process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c755fFv1Rnk)

Comment: 1 GB - it's memory of: variables and cache of app. Not libs + app in folder.

Comment: 2GB = 1GB(heap space) + 1GB(non-heap space).   Non-heap space contains memory which is used by gc/code cache/thread stack/native memory(jni/jna used)

Comment: Tell me, is there a way to reduce memory? 1GB(heap space) is space of variables, and I and I can control it (with more or less quality). And how can i controll 1GB(non-heap space)?